# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10 frezees grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

For more than a year I have used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10 on my laptop Asus Zenbook UX305CA, without any problems.

Suddenly, some weeks ago, out of the blue, an attempt to boot Ubuntu freezes the screen, leaving it black whiteout any ways to contact the system.
Windows was bootable as usual.

To get in contact with Ubuntu I had to use "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-123 (generic recovery mode)", from grub's boot menu. This gave me Ubuntu in a miserable resolution. Attempt to restart freezes the screen like before.
I then decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS hoping to get rid of problems that way.

The situation is now, that Windows is ok as before, and Ubuntu is booting in 1 out of 5 attempts, but mostly freezes with a black screen. To get in contact I have to press and hold the Power-on key a while, then release the key.

Now, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from a bootable USB-stick. Result: Windows ok, Ubuntu as before. Though, I am able to get a nice Ubuntu via '5.4.0-56 generic(recovery mode)' from grub's boot screen.
I tried different solutions to the problem from stack overflow.com and other sites, starting with setting nomodeset in /etc/default/grub and ending with boot-repair (Pastebin see below).
How do I get a normal dual boot back?

```
PC:         Asus Zenbook UX305CA
Mmemory     7,7 GiB
CPU         Intel® Core™ m3-6Y30 CPU @ 0.90GHz × 4
Graphic     lvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
Disk        256,1 GB
OS          Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Type        64-bit
GNOME-v     3.36.3     
Window      X11
```

Ubuntu Pastebin:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8ycqyWfVhF/

Comment: You say Ubuntu freezes in the sense that it does not boot into the given partition? So you get a black screen? Do you see any errors? 

Give this a try. https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: I get a black screen, totally empty, no error messages.
The problem did not arose after installing Windows. Windows has been there all the time.
The only way to get rid of the black screen is to press and hold the Power-on key a while, then release the key. Then I get the dual boot grub window again. If I am lucky Ubuntu boots, mostly I get the black screen again. The only reliable way to get Ubuntu is via '5.4.0-56 generic(recovery mode)' from grub's boot screen.
Rather awkward!

Comment: black screaned. Before this started happening ,did you made any changes. Did you update some core packages (and got some error messages)? Have you tried `boot-repair`? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I did not do any unusual things and got no error messages.
As previously written I tried boot-repair. For Pastebin see above.

Comment: In /etc/default/grub replace the value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash debug --verbose"

then run: sudo update-grub

This will enable printing of debugging information during the boot sequence. This should information us what is going in when the black screen error occurs. Go ahead and then post your findings.

Comment: Replaced the value in Grub and updated.
What happens now is as before:
(Some parts translated from danish)
To get in touch with Ubuntu I choose
- Advanced options for Ubuntu,
- Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-56 generic (recovery mode),

Then I get a black screen with the following in the upper, left corner 
- Loading Linux 5.4.0-56 generic
- Loading start ram-disk
- A lot is now loaded, very fast, impossible to identify.

After that I choose
- resume, Back to normal start-up.

Now I get a black screen with a blinking dash in the upper, left corner. After a while Ubuntu boots.

Comment: It boots? So the issue is solved? If not then post the error that you get when the system fails to boot.

Comment: I have always been able to boot som kind of Ubuntu. The problem is I have to use this odd work around with using recovery mode nearly all the time.

Comment: If you don't use recovery mode, what error do you get? With the debug flag in the grub file, you should now see an error message.

Comment: After pressing *Ubuntu in the grub dual mode screen I just  get an frozen, empty, black screen. No messages at all.  To get in contact with the system I have to press the Power-on key and hold it for a while. Then the grub dual mode screen reappear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see anything wrong with your pastebin and without any more information there isn't anything I can do to help you solve your issue. Maybe try reinstalling Ubuntu, or if you have some backups of the system then you could try reverting back and seing if the issue persists.

Comment: I have already once reinstalled Ubuntu. 
Thank you for your advises, pip1726.